# Date with time ranging 15 minutes

Tags: java, jpa

I want to check the current date time is exactly 15 minute

Example:
 10:15,10:30,10:45,11:00,11:15,11:30,11:45 ....

How can i achieve this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

int s=minutes %15;

if((minutes == 0 ) && s==0 )
{
    System.out.print("Time ");   

}
```

can i use like this ..

Comment: Use the modulus operator on the date's minute value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
if(minute % 15 == 0) 
{
    System.out.println("the current date time is exactly 15 minute");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06):

```
CronTrigger cronTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                       .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("* 0/15 * * * ?"))
                       .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)` should help you out.

```
public void minuteOfHour(){

    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
}
```

Or even better, consider Joda Time's DateTime API. It provides a convenient minuteOfHour method.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minuteOfHour()

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isFifteenMin(DateTime datetime)
    return (Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("m").format(datetime))%15==0) ? true :     false;
}
```